# NullPointerException (onClick event)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with a `NullPointerException` when I click the "SignUp" button. Can anyone help please? Thanx in advance...

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button loginButton,signUpBtn;
    EditText txtUsername,txtPassword;
    private AppDataSouce datasource;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        signUpBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
        signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("nulll1"+txtUsername.getText().toString());
                datasource.createUser(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("nulll2" + txtUsername);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Sucessfully", 3000).show();

                System.out.println("nulll3" + txtUsername.getText().toString());

                Intent listActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowListActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(listActivityIntent);

            }
        });
}
```

**LogCat**:

```
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at           com.example.androidlower.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-11 13:18:46.772: E/AndroidRuntime(14331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the logcat trace.

Second use Log.d Log.e Log.w ... instead of Syste.out.println

Comment: are u sure R.id.signUpBtn is in layout.activity_main? Please post XML too. And please, entire logcat

Comment: please post it as code

Comment: @StefanoMunarini Yes It is in xml file...

Comment: which one is line 35?

Comment: @AnkurJagani The problem is inside the Click code or before?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anywhere you are creating object of `AppDataSouce datasource;`
and you are using `datasource` without creating object, hence it is just a reference and not an object.

```
datasource.createUser(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString());
```

Hence it is giving `nullpointer exception.`

Comment: Thank You For Reply Sir...I Have Made That Changes But Still i Am Getting Same problem....r u need Any SanpShot Of it 4 better clarification....

Comment: plz provide the xml, i would like to have a look at it too.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to declare datasource before use it!

```
datasource = new AppDataSouce(whatever);
```

Comment: Thank You For Reply Sir...I Have Made That Changes But Still i Am Getting Same problem....r u need Any SanpShot Of it 4 better clarification....

Answer (score 0):

`datasource` doesn't seem to be initialized any where in `onCreate()`. If an object isn't intialized, how do intend to use it.

Before setting clickListener, create this object.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    datasource = new AppDataSouce();
     ....
}
```

Comment: Thank You For Reply Sir...I Have Made That Changes But Still i Am Getting Same problem....r u need Any SanpShot Of it 4 better clarification....